# Handle back press on top fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments

I have two fragments [A] and [B].

In fragment [A] , I want to ignore back press so I have the following code

```
View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_confirmation, container, false);

    view.setOnKeyListener(new View.OnKeyListener() {

        @Override
        public boolean onKey(View v, int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {

            if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) {
                return true;
            }

            return false;
        }
    });
```

This works fine on fragment [A]. When i add fragment [B] to backstack, seems fragment [B] cannot handle back press although, the logic to ignore back press was only in fragment[A] . Can anyone explain this strange behaviour?

Comment: post your both fragments code

Comment: post your fragement code and if you are getting any error in the locat ppost that also.

Comment: seems fragment [B] cannot handle back press...what is happening in Frag. B that you are saying it cannot handle back press? How are you expecting Frag. B to behave?

Comment: I am expecting fragment [B] to handle back press and close. the code to ignore backpress is only in fragment [A] so why does [B] ignore back press?

Answer (score 0):

try this may be it works.Override the back key in onResume ...

```
@Override
public void onResume() {

    super.onResume();

    getView().setFocusableInTouchMode(true);
    getView().requestFocus();
    getView().setOnKeyListener(new View.OnKeyListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onKey(View v, int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {

            if (event.getAction() == KeyEvent.ACTION_UP && keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK){

                // handle back button    
                return true;
                }

            return false;
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: I have this code in fragment [A] and it works as expected. Issue is , fragment [B] seems to ignore back key press, although the above code is only in fragment [A].

Comment: use above two apis(setFocusableInTouchMode and requestFocus) on view and than check..